# Can this be written as a query instead of using a function?

Tags: sql, plsql

I have a table in this format (similar to the class schedule you had in college):

```
create table match_times
(
  match_time     varchar2(20 char),
  match_sun_day  char(1 char),
  match_mon_day  char(1 char),
  match_tue_day  char(1 char),
  match_wed_day  char(1 char),
  match_thu_day  char(1 char),
  match_fri_day  char(1 char),
  match_sat_day  char(1 char)
)
comment on column match_times.match_time is 'E.g. ''08:00-08:50''';
comment on column match_times.match_sun_day is '''U'' or null';
comment on column match_times.match_mon_day is '''M'' or null';
comment on column match_times.match_tue_day is '''T'' or null';
comment on column match_times.match_wed_day is '''W'' or null';
comment on column match_times.match_thu_day is '''R'' or null';
comment on column match_times.match_fri_day is '''F'' or null';
comment on column match_times.match_sat_day is '''S'' or null';
```

I want to write a query that will get me for e.g.:

```
8:00 - 9:00 MTF
9:00 - 10:15 TR
```

This can be done easily using a function, but I'm curious if this can be done by using an SQL query. This isn't important, it's just for knowledge:)

EDIT: Sorry, I missed out one vital clarification. There can be multiple rows per match time. It could have MF on one row and W on the next. Now I understand why you folks were asking for the actual create table statement.

Comment: Can you include the actual create table statement?  That would provide a better idea of what the table looks like.  I can't really tell what is going on from this format.

Comment: Can you post more information about the table? For instance, the data types? Are the week days boolean values? Is Time VARCHAR?

Comment: Sorry, I posted the actual create table statement now. I thought it would be more readable with sample data instead of the datatype.

Comment: what do you save in "match_sun_day" ... "match_sat_day" columns? 0,1? What do you save for match_time='08:00-'08:50' which is on sunday and friday?

Comment: I've posted a sample value next to each column. Your record would be stored like this: '08:00-08:50', 'U', null, null, null, null, 'F'

Comment: Then Tom H. got answer for ya.

Comment: Oops. Dumb me. It can be multiple rows. Sorry for the confusion. It is possible to have multiple rows like: 1. '08:00-08:50', 'U', null, null, null, null, null 2.  '08:00-08:50', null, null, null, null, null, 'F'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
with days AS (
  select
    match_time,
    max(coalesce(match_sun_day, '')) sun,
    max(coalesce(match_mon_day, '')) mon,
    max(coalesce(match_tue_day, '')) tue,
    max(coalesce(match_wed_day, '')) wed,
    max(coalesce(match_thu_day, '')) thu,
    max(coalesce(match_fri_day, '')) fri,
    max(coalesce(match_sat_day, '')) sat
  from
    match_times
  group by
    match_time
)
  select
    match_time + ' ' + sun+mon+tue+wed+thu+fri+sat
  from
    days
```

I don't have an install handy to test it.  Worst case, if your DB doesn't order empty string before non-empty string for `max`, replace `''` with `'a'` and then put a case in for each day on the string building.

Comment: Good job! Impressive that you did it mentally. Small typo - replace + with ||. Thanks for replying.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you only have one row per unique timespan (no primary key is listed):

```
SELECT
    match_time,
    COALESCE(match_sun_time, '') +
    COALESCE(match_mon_time, '') +
    COALESCE(match_tue_time, '') +
    COALESCE(match_wed_time, '') +
    COALESCE(match_thu_time, '') +
    COALESCE(match_fri_time, '') +
    COALESCE(match_sat_time, '')
FROM
    Match_Times
```

Comment: My bad. There can be multiple rows per match time. Sorry I forgot to mention this. Your query is correct otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. But that is a terrible schema, making queries like "show me the total number of hours a professor is teaching this semester" very difficult.

Comment: You're right. Unfortunately, I've no control over this table.